# Simple method to estimate $\sigma^2$ from i.i.d. samples of $y_i \sim N(\theta_i, \sigma^2)$

Tags: regression, self-study, estimation, nonparametric, inference

This is a normal means model: given $N$ i.i.d $y_i \sim N(\theta_i, \sigma^2)$ or equivalently 
$$
y_i = \theta_i + \varepsilon_i\, \text{  where }\varepsilon_i \text{ are i.i.d }   \sim N(0, \sigma^2)\,,\qquad i = 1, \ldots, N.
$$

I want to estimate unknown $\sigma^2$. Note: the values of $y_i$ appear to be relatively heavy tailed.

---

My initial approach was to order $y_i$ and consider the square of the differences $(y_{(i+1)} - y_{(i)})^2$, but I am not sure this is the right approach.

How can I do this? What are the natural assumptions I have to assume regarding $\theta_i$? Any comments or suggestions are welcom

P.S.
Estimating $\sigma^2$ is an intermediate step, my final goal is to find an estimate for $\theta_i$.

Histogram of the $y_i$ samples

[image: Hiatogram of the samples]

Comment: It's hard to figure out what you are trying to do.  If the $\theta_i$ are parameters, the maximum likelihood solution is $\hat\theta_i=y_i$ and $\hat\sigma^2=0$.  Shall we presume you know the $\theta_i$ then?  (That seems to be at odds with your final goal, though.)  Since you remark the values of the $y_i$ are "heavy tailed", shouldn't we understand that to mean you don't think the Normal distribution is appropriate?  Why, then, invoke a Normal distribution in the first place?

Comment: Do you know anything (or are you prepared to assume something) about the distribution of the $\theta_i$ values?

Comment: @whuber. No there are no additional assumptions but I have added histogram plot. In the [Larry Wassermann's all of non-parametric statistics](http://web.stanford.edu/class/ee378a/books/book2.pdf)  chapter 7 he talks about normal means - on  page 146 he says - "Throughout this chapter we take $\sigma^2$  as known. In practice, we would need to estimate the variance using one of the methods discussed in Chapter 5". But I didn't find any appropriate method in chapter 5.

Comment: You appear to misunderstand this model: it is possible to estimate $\sigma$ only when you have *repeated* values drawn from at least one of the distributions--and preferably from all the distributions.  That is why Wasserman uses *double* subscripts: one for $\theta_i$ and another for the replication within $i$.  Without any repetitions, the result is what I described in my first comment.

Comment: Your desire to look at differences in time suggests that you think the $\theta_i$ values change slowly over time. You should make any such knowledge or assumption explicit.